# why is postgresql fooling me with timestamps?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

I'm working on a system and I'm trying to minimize the errors that timezones could introduce and so I'm using timestamp fields on the (postgresql) DB but I use seconds from UNIX epoch when I create the records and when I read the record (use `EXTRACT(EPOCH)` to read, use `TO_TIMESTAMP()` when inserting).

This way I would be able to get rid of the timezone problem. or so I though. After digging a little bit I'm finding that postgresql is getting a little bit confused when reading the values from the table. Consider this query:

```
select current_timestamp, extract(EPOCH from current_timestamp), id, last_gps_read, 
    extract(EPOCH from current_timestamp) - extract(EPOCH 
from last_gps_read) from sometable where id=1
```

Which gives

```
              now              |    date_part     | id |      last_gps_read       |    ?column?     
-------------------------------+------------------+----+--------------------------+-----------------
 2018-03-21 23:26:07.263931-06 | 1521696367.26393 |  1 | 2018-03-21 23:26:00.5273 | 21606.736631155
```

Notice how the dates are very close from each other (only roughly 7-second difference?).

And so when I used the `extract(EPOCH from x)` trick I though that the difference would give me some 7 seconds.... instead I'm getting ~21607 (I'm on GMT-6, that explains why it's some 21600 seconds of difference). This is definitely not cool because that means that when reporting the seconds since UNIX epoch for both dates it's introducing the time zone somehow when reporting the seconds for the data coming from the table (I just checked and the seconds since UNIX epoch for current_timestamp is correct).

What is the rational for this? Cause it sounds A LOT like a bug to me.

PS I could consider changing the field type on the DB to use an integer number to hold the actual seconds since UNIX epoch so I definitely get rid of this but it sounds like an overkill.

Comment: Using `timestamp without time zone` instead of `timestamp with time zone` to record events is almost always the wrong thing to do and will get you in trouble unless you are dealing with data from only one time zone.

Comment: Note that even UTC has leap seconds, which must be known to your TZ conversion table(s). Currently TAI<--> UTC differ in 37 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)` always calculates the time relative to a time in GMT (the well-known `01.01.1970 00:00:00+00`). If you *convert* your *current time* to GMT, you will get the timestamp `2018-03-21 17:26:00.5273+00` which has a difference of 6 hours and approx 7 seconds, or approx `6 * 3600 + 7 = 21607` from the GPS timestamp.

You may convert your GPS time to local time, or subtract `21600` from the timestamp difference to get the desired result.

Comment: But why is there any TZ adjustment in the calculation of seconds since UNIX epoch in the first place??? For a given moment in time (which is what we are holding on a timestamp), it should always return the same number of seconds since UNIX epoch regardless of the TZ where I'm standing.

Comment: The calculation is relative to the beginning of the epoch, which is a time in UTC. Your timestamp has a timezone which `EXTRACT` must take into account when calculating the time. I think the cleanest solution to your problem would be adding the GPS times in the correct timezon to your database.

Comment: Look.... let's say we are talking about a given event in time: My birth. If you ask for my birth to a server that was located in San Francisco, CA, it should tell you that I was born on Nov 25th 1975 roughly at 10 PM... however, if you ask for that date to a server that is located in Maracaibo, Venezuela (where i was born), it will say Nov 26th 2 AM. Or something like that. Sure... it makes sense that if I ask Extract for day of month, it should include TZ for the calculation. _However_ if you ask for seconds since UNIX epoch, both servers **should** say the same amount regardless of TZ.

Comment: Suppose that were two Postgres servers on your birthday. One in San Francisco and the other one in Maracaibo. When you saw the light of day, `SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW())` was executed on both. Both returned exactly the same number of seconds, while the local timestamp on both locations were different. The operation of `EPOCH` is correct. But if you want a different behavior, you have to adjust it. I see no problem why you don't import the GPS times in local time. Then everything should work the way you need it to. It will also make it easier for you to work with your tables.

Comment: But @clemens, that's the funny thing. If you check the query I used, extract (EPOCH) when providing current_timestamp takes the local time, *considers the time zone* and providess the number of seconds correctly. When I use it on the data from the table it behaves _differently_. It does something like: I take the local time where I am, I then use this time on GMT+0 (in other words, it disregards the timezone) and then we calculate the numbers of seconds. Why does it behave differently when using current_timestamp and when reading from the table? Anyway.... will read the answers +thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

somewhat doubling @clemens answer with samples...

to match your timezone:

```
t=# set timezone to 'GMT+6';
SET
```

what you do:

```
t=# with c("ct", last_gps_read) as (values('2018-03-21 23:26:07.263931-06'::timestamptz,'2018-03-21 23:26:00.5273'::timestamp))
select ct
, extract(EPOCH from ct)
, last_gps_read
, extract(EPOCH from ct) - extract(EPOCH from last_gps_read)
from c;
              ct               |    date_part     |      last_gps_read       |    ?column?
-------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------
 2018-03-21 23:26:07.263931-06 | 1521696367.26393 | 2018-03-21 23:26:00.5273 | 21606.736631155
(1 row)
```

what you should do:

```
t=# with c("ct", last_gps_read) as (values('2018-03-21 23:26:07.263931-06'::timestamptz,'2018-03-21 23:26:00.5273'::timestamp))
select ct
, extract(EPOCH from ct)
, last_gps_read
, extract(EPOCH from ct - last_gps_read)
from c;
              ct               |    date_part     |      last_gps_read       | date_part
-------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 2018-03-21 23:26:07.263931-06 | 1521696367.26393 | 2018-03-21 23:26:00.5273 |  6.736631
(1 row)
```

why: you divide `double precision` from `double precision` and get `epoch aware of time zone` - `epoch not aware of timezone`. So your result is expected. And [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). What I propose doing is using `interval` for division on timestamps, no matter aware of time zone or not (as interval operates both) and THEN extracting the epoch from `interval`. This way you don't need to adjust your timezone or unify the timestamp with time zone to `AT TIME ZONE 'GTM'` or whatever...